# ExpressionType's 'GreaterThanOrEqual' to string '>='

Tags: c#, expression-trees

Is there an easy way to take an expression type and get the actual operator?

For example:

I have a string that was an ExpressionType of "GreaterThanOrEqual". 
For easier viewing for clients, I'd like it to be ">=" when I output it to a string for them.

I don't want to have to hard code the conversion manually if there is something that will do this for me already in the framework.

I'd like to do this for a few of the the expression types.

Comment: Have you tried calling `ToString()` on the whole expression?

Comment: Yes, it just outputs the name of the enum "GreaterThanOrEqual"

Comment: I don't mean the `ExpressionType`, I mean the whole `Expression`. For example, the code `Expression<Func<bool>> e = () => Math.Abs(-1) >= 2;
Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());` outputs `() => (Abs(-1) >= 2)`.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for.  I want the operator that the ExpressionType will be.  So "GreaterThanOrEqual" will be ">=" when output to text. I don't want a whole expression.